# How to submit a feature request for chmod linux command

Tags: permissions, chmod

Note: I believe this question doesn't fit the SO guidelines for question types, but if you can, please move it to appropriate section of the SE network or please tell me where it would be appropriate to put this question.

The question is how can I suggest a new feature request (or submit a patch with that feature implemented) for the Unix-like tool "chmod"?

The feature I would like to see in the chmod tool is to specify an option (e.g. "-d") which would make chmod only change modes of directories, not touching regular files. This would make it more convenient than using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt), which makes use of the "find" tool:

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: send your requests to  `coreutils@gnu.org`. See `Enhancement requests` in the following page http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

Comment: What is wrong with `chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w /opt/lampp/htdocs`? From the manual: `The execute/search bits if the file is a directory or any of the execute/search bits are set in the original (unmodified) mode.`

Comment: It seems it is a rejected prposal `chmod -d`  `to set perms on just directories. The X mode, or find with chmod was deemed sufficient` as seen here http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/rejected_requests.html

Comment: Rinzwind, what is wrong is that your comment does not address the asked question. Your answer only helps if a user needs to set +x option alone for directories. There are cases which, for example, demand resetting wrongly set directory attributes and those cases cannot be handled using your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer completely ignores the request in favour of addressing the how you contact the right people to make a feature request in an upstream project.

This request is already been asked and rejected. The behaviour is already possible through existing mechanisms (see the comments on your question).

---

For the best way to get something like that under the nose of somebody who makes the decisions, you need to find out where a package comes from. Start by tracking down the package for the command:

```
$ dpkg -S `which chmod`
coreutils: /bin/chmod
```

Then look at the `coreutils` package details:

```
$ apt-cache show coreutils
Package: coreutils
Essential: yes
Priority: required
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 5920
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Michael Stone <mstone@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 8.20-3ubuntu5
Replaces: mktemp, timeout
Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) | install-info
Pre-Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8), libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8), libc6 (>= 2.15), libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
Conflicts: timeout
Filename: pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.20-3ubuntu5_amd64.deb
Size: 2477552
MD5sum: 7ebb74af562ad4b6f3c767f9a94e54fc
SHA1: 8afa0e8aff4bf33d946d1c301a2aa4b250e702f9
SHA256: e54ba21d60d20594e33e4fe2569621ed1312198014a81c7592934ed8dbb85ba0
Description-en_GB: GNU core utilities
 This package contains the basic file, shell and text manipulation
 utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system.
 .
 Specifically, this package includes: arch base64 basename cat chcon chgrp
 chmod chown chroot cksum comm cp csplit cut date dd df dir dircolors
 dirname du echo env expand expr factor false flock fmt fold groups head
 hostid id install join link ln logname ls md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod mktemp
 mv nice nl nohup nproc od paste pathchk pinky pr printenv printf ptx pwd
 readlink rm rmdir runcon sha*sum seq shred sleep sort split stat stty sum
 sync tac tail tee test timeout touch tr true truncate tsort tty uname
 unexpand uniq unlink users vdir wc who whoami yes
Description-md5: ca29325ab0239421f7b6be11369cc121
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: http://gnu.org/software/coreutils
Description-md5: ca29325ab0239421f7b6be11369cc121
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m
Task: minimal
```

Launchpad and Debian are red herrings here. They're very downstream. The project is a GNU one. The Homepage link is a good start here: http://gnu.org/software/coreutils

On there you'll find the various mailing lists you'll need to convince people on, as well as bug trackers (but I'm not sure how they'll take a feature request - check the rules first).